# SQLAlchemy ORM clause using EXTRACT and AT TIME ZONE?

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy to connect to a Postgres DB, I'm working with a table of football games that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE game (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

(In reality, of course, there are many more columns, all of which are irrelevant to the current question.)

I'm building a query that would allow me to pull all games that happen on a given day (or days) of the week. Since timestamps are stored in UTC, many evening games would register as having been played on the following day if I just extracted the day of week without any further transformation — e.g. a game in Denver at 7:00pm on Monday would have a -7h offset from UTC, and `EXTRACT(dow FROM date)` would return 2 (Tuesday). Furthermore, I can't currently guarantee that our DB will be set to a US timezone every time I make the query. So were I to construct a query in raw SQL to return all games on Monday or Thursday, I'd do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM game
WHERE EXTRACT(dow FROM game.date AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles') IN (1, 4);
```

However, I haven't figured out an elegant way of doing it using the SQLAlchemy ORM. Were it just a matter of the `EXTRACT` clause, I could do it like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import extract

days_of_week = [1, 4]
q = session.query(Game)
q = q.filter(extract('dow', Game.date).in_(days_of_week))
mon_thurs_games = q.all()
```

But we still need to offset our time zone, and this is where I'm stumped. My current solution is a bit hacky, using `text()` to throw the above SQL clause into the ORM query, but it works:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

days_of_week = [1, 4]
q_text = "EXTRACT(dow FROM game.date AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles') IN :days"
q = session.query(Game)
q = q.filter(text(q_text).bindparams(days=tuple(days_of_week)))
mon_thurs_games = q.all()
```

Which brings me to the question: is there a way of doing this to properly leverage the SQLAlchemy ORM API? Or even a different query that better lends itself to the ORM approach? A couple things I've considered:

1. Use the bind in `session` to send a `SET timezone TO 'America/Los_Angeles'` command each time I run the query so I can just use `extract('dow', Game.date)`, (doesn't seem particularly efficient)
2. Add a `day_of_week` column to the game table (makes for a very straightforward query, but redundant to `date`)

Any/all suggestions appreciated, thanks!